# How to correctly input dask Dataframe as parameter to a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

When i am passing a Dask Dataframe as parameter he is converting to pandas Dataframe.

```py
print(type(sellout_df))
simulate_sku_predictions(sellout_df.loc[(sellout_df['sku'] == sku) & (sellout_df['store_id'] == store)].compute(), store, sku)
```

Prints => `<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>`

Entering on defined function

```py
def simulate_sku_predictions(sellout_sku_df, store, sku):
    print(type(sellout_sku_df))
```

Prints => `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

I can't use compute and dask functions.

I'm new to dask but i don't think  it's appropriate converting in the middle of the code if "i don't have to".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`dask.DataFrame.compute()` returns a Pandas DataFrame](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute). Thus, the code is not passing a Dask DataFrame to `simulate_sku_predictions`. The argument,

```
sellout_df.loc[(sellout_df['sku'] == sku) & (sellout_df['store_id'] == store)].compute()
```

is evaluated to a Pandas DataFrame *before* it is passed as an argument to `simulate_sku_predictions`.

If you remove the call to `compute()`, then `sellout_df.loc[...]` will be a Dask DataFrame, and you could pass that to `simulate_sku_predictions`.